# Will installing ROS on 14.10 destroy my X server?

Tags: xorg, 14.10

I was going through the installation process for ROS in ubuntu.I saw that I they have an issue for 14.04 which destroys the X server

Will it do the same for 14.10?

Not sure what to do next so thought would ask it here if anybody's in the same dilemma.

Here's the part which I am referring to
http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation-1

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 isn't supported anymore since July 2015... You should use 12.04 LTS, 14.04 LTS or 15.04.

Comment: So I won't be able to install ROS at all on 14.10?

Comment: Likely you'll be able to install. But please notice that questions about unsupported releases are off-topic on Ask Ubuntu. (See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @user300458 Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

It's suggesting you install Utopic-level packages over Trusty (which Trusty allows through its HWE stacks). You're already on Utopic so you don't need to do what it's saying at all. It likely won't be able to find many of those packages.

But Utopic is dead and not getting security updates. If I were you, I'd [upgrade to Vivid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Upgrades) before doing anything and then install. ROS has a repo targeting Vivid too.